# Synchronize data in two arrays with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm using AngularJS (with ng-table) to generate two arrays and I want them to be syncronised. For example, I have [A, B, C] values in both tables and if I filter the first with "A", i want only [A] in the second one too.

The problem seems to be that the *$scope* isn't the same for the two tables (even if they are into the same page), so the data is not common between them. So I tried to force the controller to be the same with `nb-controller`:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" ng-controller="myController" id="tableA">
[...]
</table>
<table ng-table="tableParams" ng-controller="myController" id="tableB">
[...]
</table>
```

But unfortunally it doesn't work...

Here is an extract of my controller:

```
var data = ['A','B','C'];

$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
  page : 1, // show first page
  count : 15, // count per page
  filter : {
    filter_dict : '{}',
  },
  sorting : {
    id : 'asc',// initial sorting
  }
},
{
  counts: [15, 30, 50, 100],
  total : $rootScope.data.length, // length of data
  getData : function($defer, params) {
    $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(),  params.page() * params.count()));
  },
  $scope:$scope
});
```

Do you have an idea of what should I do ?

Thanks !

Comment: Use a service to manage a single data source. Sorry don't have time to write out an example, at work.

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply wrap both tables in the same controller and bind them both to the same source?

Comment: @DavidL : It's what I've made with `ng-controller` no ?

Comment: No, that's not how `ng-controller` works.  What you've done in this case is create two instances of the controller, each with an independent collection.

Comment: Why don't you put the `ng-controller` on the element above the both tables?

Comment: @Synapse : That's the first thing I made but the first table was empty in this case...

Comment: @DavidL : So how can I wrap them in the same controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you should be able to wrap both tables in the same `ng-controller` and bind to the same table instance, as demonstrated by this similar [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXXpvW?editors=101).

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" id="tableA">
        [...]
    </table>
    <table ng-table="tableParams" id="tableB">
        [...]
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: As I said to Synapse, that's the first thing I tried but in this case, the second table was correctly filled but the first one was empty...

Comment: @Dynamite then there's either something wrong with how you've set it up or you have an older version of ngTable that doesn't properly support it.  If you could provide a plunkr or fiddle that reproduces the issue, that would be very helpful in giving you a more useful answer.  The codepen I linked CLEARLY demonstrates that the behavior works as intended.

Comment: Thanks ! It was due to a wrong version of ngTable, I made an update and it now works !